# Sending serialized Mat object to another computer using zeromq in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, zeromq

Hello I am trying to send a mat object to another computer using zeromq and boost.

**this is my serialization.h file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(cv::Mat)
namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {

        /*** Mat ***/
        template<class Archive>
        void save(Archive & ar, const cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            size_t elemSize = m.elemSize(), elemType = m.type();

            ar & m.cols;
            ar & m.rows;
            ar & elemSize;
            ar & elemType; // element type.
            size_t dataSize = m.cols * m.rows * m.elemSize();


            for (size_t dc = 0; dc < dataSize; ++dc) {
                ar & m.data[dc];
            }
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void load(Archive & ar, cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            int cols, rows;
            size_t elemSize, elemType;

            ar & cols;
            ar & rows;
            ar & elemSize;
            ar & elemType;

            m.create(rows, cols, elemType);
            size_t dataSize = m.cols * m.rows * elemSize;

            //cout << "reading matrix data rows, cols, elemSize, type, datasize: (" << m.rows << "," << m.cols << "," << m.elemSize() << "," << m.type() << "," << dataSize << ")" << endl;

            for (size_t dc = 0; dc < dataSize; ++dc) {
                ar & m.data[dc];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is how I serialize my Mat object and send it.

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "Serialization.h"
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


std::string save( const cv::Mat & mat )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive toa( oss );
    toa << mat;

    return oss.str();
}



int main () {
    Mat img = imread("/Users/Rodrane/Downloads/barbara.pgm", 0);   // Read the file


    std::string serialized = save(img);


    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    //  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        zmq::message_t request (sizeof(serialized));
        memcpy (request.data (), &serialized, sizeof(serialized));
        std::cout << "Sending Hello " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send (request);

        //  Get the reply.
        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv (&reply);
        std::cout << "Received World " << request_nbr << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;



}
```

and this is how I recieve my serialized object and try to show it.

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "Serialization.h"
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

void load( cv::Mat & mat, const char * data_str )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << data_str;

    boost::archive::text_iarchive tia( ss );
    tia >> mat;
}

int main () {
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");
    cv::Mat object;

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t recivedData;
        socket.recv (&recivedData);
        std::string rpl = std::string(static_cast<char*>(recivedData.data()), recivedData.size());
        const char *cstr = rpl.c_str();
        load(object,cstr);
        imshow("asdasd",object);
        //  Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply (8);
        memcpy (reply.data (), "Recieved", 8);
        socket.send (reply);
  }



}
```

When I run this 2 projects I retrieve an error which is

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   zmq::error_t: Interrupted system call

Since it happens the time I run my client project I assume server recieves data but either its corrupted or there is a problem with de-serialize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't go through all your code, but this is 100% wrong:

```
std::string serialized = save(img);
//  ...
zmq::message_t request (sizeof(serialized));
memcpy (request.data (), &serialized, sizeof(serialized));
```

`sizeof(std::string)` has nothing to do with size of the string held, and you can't memcpy from `std::string` object. What you want to do is:

```
zmq::message_t request (serialized.length());
memcpy (request.data (), serialized.c_str(), serialized.length());
```

Might be other errors as well, but this just sticks out.